# SSRS 2008 R2 Auto Render

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, render

Is it possible to force a SSRS 2008 R2 report to render in the report manager when you change a parameter instead of having to use the mouse to click the View Report button?

Answer (score 0):

I think the feature you are after is URL Access

```
http://<Server Name>/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesSummary&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false
```

Notice the Command=Render and Format=HTML4.0 This will cause the report to render to html

For this to work, you need to make sure all the required report parameters that do not have a default values are sent in via the url as well.

Learn more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx